# git branches are not visible

Tags: git, branch, git-commit

This is the first time I am using git

I have created a repo and uploaded the code for the first time from my terminal. The code was uploaded and I am able to see it in my account on github.com

I tried creating two branches and uploaded the code with some changes from my terminal i.e. `two commits`, in terminal it didn't show any error, but in my repo, I am `not able to see my branches and there the commit seems to be only 1 master commit` alone

So I tried running my `git log` in terminal

```
macbook-MBP Ojaak % git log
commit b5b17e3108139d7904c905d1d1aefe22a7395180 (HEAD -> siva)
Author: sk-master <siv@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 28 18:00:43 2021 +0530

    siva test

commit eea6ed5fe18dedd60ab714e1d3828cc2487cba3a (Dani)
Author: sk-master <siv@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 28 17:23:28 2021 +0530

    dani updated by 26th June

commit 8e9f41d4245dfb1e2e9f4ed1d00ee12d1b081240 (origin/master, master)
Author: sk-master <siv@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 28 16:28:58 2021 +0530

    code worked by Sarah
```

Here it shows the branches name and their commit time etc but those are not available in github repo

What's wrong in the way I am doing in this

I was learing about git from the following youtube playlist
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZILYABgAoo&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L8OlICbNX9u4MZ3rAt5c5GG&index=5

it is a 2016 video - it can be followed right now?

Comment: If you run `git status`, what does it say?

Comment: Also, `git branch` should list at least `master`, `Dani` and `siva`. Then try `git branch -r` to list branches on your github and check which have already been pushed (or not). *(But it sure looks like you just didn't push `Dani` and `siva`.)*

Comment: Did you push your branches to the remote repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand some basic concepts about git. Once you understand them it will be easy to work with git.

## commit

A commit is a chunk of work that's stored at a repo in a branch.

## pull

The process of downloading commits from another repo. The default repo you download from is by default called `origin`.

## push

The process of uploading commits to another repo. The default repo you upload to is by default called `origin`.

## branch

In the versioning tree, a branch is a well-defined set of commits. You can create a branch as

```
git branch yourbranch
```

which, according to the wording of your question you did successfully. You can switch branches via

```
git checkout yourbranch
```

which was also correctly done by you according to the wording of your question.

**You missed uploading your branch**:

```
git checkout thebranchtobeuploaded
git push -u origin thebranchtobeuploaded
```

The `checkout` step is not always necessary to be performed, if you are on the branch which you intend to upload, then you can omit the `checkout` step, I nevertheless have given you a bullet-proof approach. Once you do the `git push -u origin somebranch` step, your branches should appear on the origin repo. You can use multiple repos as well, but that's not the topic of this question.